# Convert JSON file to flat table

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good Afternoon,

I am still pretty new to Python but have found it particularly addicting, but there are def some "quirks" to python that have been a pain to get through. I am currently trying to take a JSON file and flatten it out into a table. There are a ton of posts, specifically here on stack overflow on converting it into a flat dict, but that doesn't allow me to convert it into a table. This has been way harder than I expected.

I am currently getting the following error, which to me seems like it is something wrong with my key generation portion.
[image]

Code:

```
import json
import os
import csv
import copy
from pandas.io.json._normalize import nested_to_record

#Basic Veriables
scriptDirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def getKeys(dictionary:dict, result:list = None, parentKey='', sep='.',skipParent = False) -> list:
    if result == None:
        result = []

    #Loop through all keeys and return unique options
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        newKey = (parentKey + sep + key if parentKey else str(key))
        if type(dictionary[key]) == dict:
            result = (getKeys(dictionary[key],result=result,parentKey = ('' if skipParent else str(newKey))))
        else:
            if key != "" and newKey not in result:
                result.append(newKey)
    return result

def convertKey(data:str,languageDict:dict):
    try:
        return languageDict[data]
    except KeyError:
        return data
    


#Read the JSON files.
#Library File
with open(os.path.join(scriptDirectory,'inventoryItem.json'), "r",encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
    lib = json.load(read_file)

#English Dictionary
with open(os.path.join(scriptDirectory,'en.json'), "r",encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
    en = json.load(read_file)


for key in lib['inventoryItem'].keys():
    print(key)
    dictTemplate = dict.fromkeys(getKeys(dictionary=lib['inventoryItem'][key],skipParent = True),None)
    print(dictTemplate)
    firstItem = 0

    try:
        with open(os.path.join(scriptDirectory,'export',f"{key}.csv"),"w", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:

            for item in lib['inventoryItem'][key]:
                entry = copy.deepcopy(dictTemplate)
                
                entry.update(nested_to_record(lib['inventoryItem'][key][item], sep='.'))
                if key == 'coin':
                    entry['name'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_COIN_NAME_{entry['id']}",languageDict=en)
                    entry['description'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_COIN_DESC_{entry['id']}",languageDict=en)
                    entry['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_message'] = convertKey(data = entry['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_message'],languageDict=en)
                    entry['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_title'] = convertKey(data = entry['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_title'],languageDict=en)
                    entry['obtainNavigatorData.button_label'] = convertKey(data = entry['obtainNavigatorData.button_label'],languageDict=en)
                
                elif key == 'consumable':
                    #print(dictTemplate)
                    pass
                    
                elif key == 'scroll':
                    del entry["fragmentMergeCost"]
                    del entry["fragmentSellCost"]
                    del entry["fragmentBuyCost"]
                    del entry["buyCost"]

                if firstItem == 0:
                    firstItem += 1
                    writer =csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=entry.keys(),delimiter = ';')
                    writer.writeheader()
                    
                writer.writerow(entry)

    except IOError:
        print("I/O error")
```

Data set thats giving me trouble.

```
    "consumable": {
        "96": {
            "id": 96,
            "rewardType": "",
            "rewardAmount": 0,
            "effectDescription": {
                "": ""
            },
            "buyCost": null,
            "sellCost": null,
            "buySpecialCost": null,
            "assetAtlas": 4,
            "assetTexture": "social_vk",
            "iconAssetTexture": "",
            "color": 1,
            "hidden": 0,
            "descLocaleId": "PLAY_AT_HOME_TICKET",
            "obtainNavigatorData": null
        },
```

Desired Output.
This is from a section called "coins", but the example data is from "consumables". Certain sections work fine, but others cause issues because the value is set to "","".

[image]

Comment: What is your desired flat table version of the gjven JSON dataset going to look like?

Comment: are great point, let me update.

Comment: According to that error message, it looks like entry has a key named `effectDescription.` (including the period).  Why is the period there?

Comment: because the effectDescription for item 96 has a k,v of "","" so when the script "joins" everything it joins the parent key + the empty key name of ""

Comment: Just a quick question. Since you have 3 types (coin, consumable and scroll) why don't you create 3 dataframes, make changes using pandas (which is more efficient/easy) and then concat them and do df.to_csv.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the solution. For anyone who wants to properly convert a JSON file to a table, this is the only solution I could come up with :)

```
import json
import os
import csv
import copy

def processJSON(initialDict:dict, createTemplate:bool = False, existingKeys:dict = None, parentKey:str = None, sep:str ='.', skipParent:bool = False) -> dict:

    outPut = (existingKeys if existingKeys else {})
    
    #Loop through all keeys and return unique options
    for key in initialDict.keys():

        #Create needed variables
        keyTitle = str(parentKey + sep + key if parentKey else key)

        #Loop
        if type(initialDict[key]) == dict:
            parentTitle = ('' if skipParent else keyTitle)
            outPut.update(processJSON(initialDict=initialDict[key], existingKeys = outPut, createTemplate = createTemplate, parentKey = parentTitle, sep = sep))
        elif keyTitle not in outPut.keys():
            keyValue = str('' if createTemplate else initialDict[key])
            outPut[keyTitle] = keyValue

    return dict(outPut)

def convertKey(data:str,languageDict:dict):
    try:
        return languageDict[data]
    except KeyError:
        return data
    
#Basic Veriables
scriptDirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

#Read the JSON files.
#Library File
with open(os.path.join(scriptDirectory,'inventoryItem.json'), "r",encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
    lib = json.load(read_file)

#English Dictionary
with open(os.path.join(scriptDirectory,'en.json'), "r",encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
    en = json.load(read_file)

for key in lib['inventoryItem'].keys():
    firstItem = True
    header =  processJSON(initialDict=lib['inventoryItem'][key], createTemplate=True, skipParent=True)

    try:
        with open(os.path.join(scriptDirectory,'export',f"{key}.csv"),"w", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:

            for item in lib['inventoryItem'][key]:
                
                #Copy Header because Python sucks
                row = dict(copy.deepcopy(header))
                row.update(processJSON(initialDict=lib['inventoryItem'][key][item]))

                if key == 'coin':
                    row['name'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_COIN_NAME_{row['id']}",languageDict=en)
                    row['description'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_COIN_DESC_{row['id']}",languageDict=en)
                    row['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_message'] = convertKey(data = row['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_message'],languageDict=en)
                    row['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_title'] = convertKey(data = row['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_title'],languageDict=en)
                    row['obtainNavigatorData.button_label'] = convertKey(data = row['obtainNavigatorData.button_label'],languageDict=en)
                
                elif key == 'consumable':
                    row['name'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_CONSUMABLE_NAME_{row['id']}",languageDict=en)
                    row['description'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_CONSUMABLE_DESC_{row['descLocaleId']}",languageDict=en)
                    row['obtainNavigatorData.button_label'] = convertKey(data = row['obtainNavigatorData.button_label'],languageDict=en)
                    row['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_message'] = convertKey(data = row['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_message'],languageDict=en)
                    row['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_title'] = convertKey(data = row['obtainNavigatorData.not_enough_title'],languageDict=en)
                    
                elif key == 'gear':
                    row['name'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_GEAR_NAME_{row['id']}",languageDict=en)
                
                elif key == 'petGear':
                    row['name'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_PET_GEAR_NAME_{row['id']}",languageDict=en)
                    
                elif key == 'pseudo':
                    row['name'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_PSEUDO_{row['constName']}",languageDict=en)
                    row['description'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_PSEUDO_DESC_{row['id']}",languageDict=en)
                 
                elif key == 'scroll':
                    row['name'] = convertKey(data = f"LIB_SCROLL_NAME_{row['id']}",languageDict=en)
                    del row["fragmentMergeCost"]
                    del row["fragmentSellCost"]
                    del row["fragmentBuyCost"]
                    del row["buyCost"]
                else:
                    print(key)
    
                if firstItem:
                    firstItem = False
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=row.keys(),delimiter = ',')
                    writer.writeheader()
                    
                writer.writerow(row)
                
    except IOError:
        print("I/O error")
```